# How to synchronize local project with online bitbucket repository

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket

I have a source code that I took from a friend, Idempiere, and I can't afford to re-download it as it weights over 2 GB.

I would like to stay updated to the recent changes done on the source code online repository.

I have installed the Git plugin in my Eclipse Indigo but now I don't now if it is even possible to do that so that it pulls only what I don't have yet and update what I do have.

Comment: http://gitref.org/remotes/

Comment: It's the default git behavour to only pull _files_ that are changed. 
Why is your repo so big anyway? Are there some binaries? You sure you need them _in_ the repo?

Also, I would recommend starting using git in a terminal, not as an Eclipse plugin. Some will disagree

Comment: @Leyonce, it'll be worth also going over your project and making generic copy of the (relevant)files you often make changes to. e.g you could have images in your project and those files are irrelevant when it comes to version control. An image is easily replaceable but lost source code.... possibly means doing it all again if version control is very bad.

Comment: If this question isn't about git you should remove the git tag and put a mercurial tag on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leyonce, iDempiere uses mercurial, not git.

There are some tips to download the big repository in one file or incrementally here:
http://www.globalqss.com/wiki/index.php/IDempiere/Download_the_Code#Tip:_Zipped_full_repo

It's also explained there how to keep it up to date.

Regards,

Carlos Ruiz

Comment: Inlcude relevant parts here, in case the linked page disapears ;)

Answer (score 3):

Git generally won't transfer objects that you already have.  Just do a `git add remote` and then you should be able to `git fetch` and only get the changes that you need.